# Linq Query using where clause in windows phone app

Tags: c#, sql, linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I have a query that should return a 5 rows from a where clause using linq2xml in windows phone   app the query i try is

```
XDocument loadedCustomData = XDocument.Load("pincodes.xml");`

var filteredData = from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")`

               where c.Attribute("PON").Equals ("Adapur")`
                 select new pincodes1()
{
   PON = c.Attribute("PostOfficeName").Value,
   PIN = c.Attribute("Pincode").Value,
   DIS = c.Attribute("Districts").Value,
   CT = c.Attribute("City").Value,
   ST = c.Attribute("State").Value
};
listBox1.ItemsSource = filteredData;
```

but then it gives system Null Exception so what's wrong in query 
here is the screenshot
[image: here it is where i get error(exception)]

and this is class file

```
namespace pincodes
{
   class pincodes1
    {

        string PostOfficeName;
        string Pincode;
        string Districts;
        string City;
        string State;
        public string PON
        {
            get { return PostOfficeName; }
            set { PostOfficeName = value; }
        }
        public string PIN
        {
            get { return Pincode; }
            set { Pincode = value; }
        }
        public string DIS
        {
            get { return Districts; }
            set { Districts = value; }
        }
        public string CT
        {
            get { return City; }
            set { City = value; }
        }
        public string ST
        {
            get { return State; }
            set { State = value; }
        } 
    }
}
```

So what is the reason for System Null exception in the  LINQ Query

Comment: what is the inner exception?

Comment: i have attached screenshot where it gives error you can check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you get value of a attribute if it is null you will get exception,  you can do as below

```
var filteredData = 
    from c in loadedCustomData.Descendants("record")
    where (string)c.Attribute("PON") == "Adapur"
    select new pincodes1()
    {
       PON = (string)c.Attribute("PostOfficeName"),
       PIN = (string)c.Attribute("Pincode"),
       DIS = (string)c.Attribute("Districts"),
       CT = (string)c.Attribute("City"),
       ST = (string)c.Attribute("State")
    };
```

Comment: i get error on where clause statement, see the attached screenshot for details